# India Banking API to Process NEFT Payments

Tags: api, payment, bank

Is there a way to send payments from the bank account to all your customers automatically in India ?

Suppose:

Every customer has a unique id and all this bank details like name, account number and NEFT code are stored in his profile. Is there a way to send money to him from a custom application by passing an api token, the customer id and the amount to be transferred ?

Thanks
Bhargava

Comment: I also need answer to this. If you found out, please share your answer.

Comment: Hi, did you found answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, you can consume API given by private operators like Pay2All or directly by Yes Bank

Links : 
http://www.pay2all.in/money-transfer-api

https://www.yesbank.in/corporate-banking/product-and-services/digital-banking/api-banking